# What does ULTRON stand for?

Tags: character, marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers-age-of-ultron

Like "Just A Rather Very Intelligent System (J.A.R.V.I.S. )", does U.L.T.R.O.N stand for something in comics or movies in Marvel Cinematic Universe?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

### Out-of-universe - it's a *name*, rather than an *acronym*.

A mix of 'Ultroids' and 'tron'

---

In an [interview](https://www.hollywoodreporter.com/heat-vision/age-ultron-creator-roy-thomas-791320) with *The Hollywood Reporter*, Roy Thomas, who co-created Ultron, answered:

> **Where did the idea for Ultron come from?**
>
> I never considered myself very good at making up names. **Some of the first creatures I made up fighting The Avengers were part of a group called the Ultroids. I've always liked that tron ending.** I had recently made up something called a psychlotron [a brainwashing device]. **So I liked that tron ending, and Ultron just came as a good name**.

Comment: With a lack of in-universe information, I've given an alternative answer that at least answers it from one point of view. Ultron doesn't stand for anything - it's a **name**. It stands to reason that in-universe it is therefore also just a name, rather than an acronym.

Comment: I agree this could be reworded to act like a direct answer.  The citation is valuable and shows the intent of the name even if not in-universe.

Comment: Do NOT confuse "psychlotron" with "cyclotron".

Answer (score 12):

### It's not an acronym.

Name "Ultron" actually [came](http://whatculture.com/comics/10-things-didnt-know-ultron?page=5) from the ancient times:

> The inspiration behind the name "Ultron" actually came from the Roman
>   god of war Mars whose full name (in terms of the version chosen for
>   Ultron's inspiration, at least) is "Mars Ultor". The literal
>   translation of Mars Ultor is actually "Mars the Avenger", which
>   essentially means that Ultron's name is a derivative of the word
>   "Avenger" - the name of the team to whom he has been a robotic thorn
>   in the side for many a year since his first appearance. Mars Ultor is
>   also the name of a cult of Mars' followers, which is also interesting
>   given that Ultron has his own cult of followers - the "Sons of Yinsen" - in the Marvel comic books.

Comment: Ultron (/ˈʌltrən/) is a fictional supervillain appearing in American comic books published by Marvel Comics. He is most recognized as a nemesis of the Avengers, and has a quasi-familial relationship with his creator Hank Pym.

Comment: @Anu7 Please quote and cite your sources when not using your own words. Thanks

Comment: Even though it's likely true that the name doesn't stand for anything, saying the name would have to be written as "U.L.T.R.O.N" is wrong. Acronyms do not have to be written in uppercase with dots between letters. They can still 'stand for something' if they are written in lowercase without dots.

Comment: __[NASA](https://twitter.com/nasa)__ stands for __National Aeronautics and Space Administration__, so not having dots does not prove it's not an acronym. - And most people don't even know that __[LASER](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laser)__ is an acronym (__Light Amplification by Stimulated Emission of Radiation__) because there are no dots.

Comment: Scuba is written in normal case and no dots though it stands for Self-Contained Underwater Breathing Apparatus.

Comment: @Oliver_C NASA and LASER are not in MCU, right? MCU always puts dots in acronyms. **S.H.I.E.L.D.**, **F.R.I.D.A.Y.**, **J.A.R.V.I.S.** — all acronyms are written with dots. I don't think Ultron would be an exception.

Comment: Who is the source of the quote? Are whatculture quoting someone else, like a writer, or just making their own assumptions?

Comment: @Longshanks If it were their own assumptions, I don't think they would call it "10 Things You Didn't Know About Ultron"

Comment: @VerNick Do they list their source for each fact at the end of the article? Otherwise how do we as readers know that what they’re saying is accurate?

Comment: @Longshanks Don't be naive. Internet is full of unconfirmed information. How do you know your interview which you quote is real and is not made up?

Comment: @VerNick I don't,but given that Roy's name is associated with another [interview](https://www.hollywoodreporter.com/heat-vision/roy-thomas-life-at-marvel-913138) on the site in 2016, and another in [2018](https://www.hollywoodreporter.com/heat-vision/stan-lee-my-final-final-saturday-comic-book-icon-1160986), it seems unlikely that the real Roy wouldn't object to the article if it wasn't genuine. All I'm saying is that the author of your article hasn't cited **where** they found their facts (comic number, author interview, personal opinion etc.), which IMO lessens the credibility of the answer.

Comment: __NASA__ [exists](http://marvelcinematicuniverse.wikia.com/wiki/NASA) in the MCU, [Agents of SHIELD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Agents_of_S.H.I.E.L.D._(season_3)) featured the government organization __[ATCU](http://marvelcinematicuniverse.wikia.com/wiki/Advanced_Threat_Containment_Unit)__ __(Advanced Threat Containment Unit)__, which is written without dots, and Tony Stark himself wrote __[FRIDAY](http://hero.wikia.com/wiki/File:FRIDAY_-_A.I_Chip_(Age_of_Ultron).png) without the dots__.

Comment: Is the "Mars Ultor" thing supposed to be from the comics or the movie? In the movie there was the __[Ultron Program](http://marvelcinematicuniverse.wikia.com/wiki/Ultron_Program)__, which then became __Ultron__.